# how to attribute colors to factor levels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

usually I use `+scale_color/fill_continuous(values=c("blue","red"))`
but here I need to do several plots where some levels does not change, so I wondered if there where a way to do something like :

```
+scale_color/fill_continuous(values=c("A":"blue","B":"red"))
```

The idea is to save to a level a specific color that will never change.

Comment: Try with `values=c("A" = "blue", "B" = "red")`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to assign this **before** you plot the data.

E.g., make a column in your dataframe with the name of the color (or color value), and use `dplyr::case_when` to conditionally assign the color based on some condition.

Comment: But what if it is a ```facet_plot``` plot ?

Comment: Then it still holds, especially so, because all information is in your dataframe

Comment: Well  since I use ```facet_plot``` I use different dataframe  ...